# Android AsyncTask .get method in Expandable List View

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to disable `setOnGroupClickListener` in `ExpandableListView` in android through a value set by `asynctask`.

```
        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {

            try {
                new checkProgressValue().execute(i).get(3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("ResultPermission", String.valueOf(permission));

            if (permission.equals(false)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true; 
            }
        }
    });
```

AsyncTask Code:

```
public class checkProgressValue extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... voids) {

        Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi()
                .checkQuizTopicForAttempt(user.getId(), topicList.get(voids[0]).getCourse_id());

        final int temp = voids[0];
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.body().getMessage() == null) {
                        progressValue = 0;
                    } else {
                        progressValue = Integer.parseInt(response.body().getMessage());
                    }
                    if (progressValue == 0 ) {
                        permission = false;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Lock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        permission = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("Permission", String.valueOf(permission));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                permission = true;
                Log.i("Permission", String.valueOf(permission));
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Program doesn't wait at `execute(i).get()` method and always return true. The Log.i in this method print permission true while in `AsyncTask` print false.
I didn't get where I'm wrong. Or is there any way i handle `onClick` in `PostExecute` method?

Comment: post code for `checkProgressValue`

Comment: code posted @LakhwinderSingh

Comment: That Retrofit operation is asynchronous already, so the `enqueue()` method immediately returns. Using `get()` for an `AsyncTask` defeats the purpose of using `AsyncTask` in the first place, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just Call this function in `onResponse` :

```
expandableListView.expandGroup(positionOfGroup);
```